# htaccess change DirectoryIndex priority to php and not html

Tags: apache, .htaccess

1. In a production server there are index.html and index.php
2. By default index.html is getting loaded.
3. I want index.php to be the default script to load and if index.php is not present then index.html can load.
4. It is a shared hosting so we do not have access to the httpd.conf file
5. So i thought of creating .htaccess file which would do the above condition.

   **What is the directive to include in .htaccess file to do so?**

Besides, here i am explaining the reason for the above.

1. The php project is done in codeigniter framework.
2. in a sub folder from the root we have oscommerce.
3. We do not have any index.html there and only index.php was present.
4. Periodically an index.html was created by some means which has an iframe code.
5. The client reports this and we keep deleting the index.html file
6. We have also changed the ftp password.
7. so what i thought as a temp solution is to make index.php be loaded as default instead of index.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the [Apache documentation for DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex), simply put the following in a `.htaccess` file in the same directory as `index.php`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Comment: In my htaccess file, how can I change directory of file the apache server is looking for? On GoDaddy hosting, i put `DirectoryIndex my-project/public/index.php` in `.htaccess` but it's not working

Comment: @Growler That would be in the Apache config. If you don’t control Apache, then you’ll have to take it up with your web host.

Answer (score 3):

`DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on Apache Directory Index configuration. You can customize it as per your needs:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml index.php index.htm
```